# Bundle over an infinite-dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Suppose that $M$ is a manifold whose points are k-dimensional sub-manifolds of another n-manifold $N$ where $n > k$ is finite. Then define a bundle $E$ over $M$ whose fibers are $\Omega^k P$ for $P \in M$. That is, the fibers are all the $k$-forms on $P$.

Question: Is the bundle $E$ trivial? How do I know?

Guess: If the ambient manifold $N$ has a non-vanishing $k$-form $\alpha$, then $E$ will be trivial because the section $s:P \mapsto \alpha|_P$ will trivialize $E$. I am guessing this is if and only if but I don't know how to show that.

Secondary question: Where do I read about this kind of infinite-dimensional setting?

Comment: What kind of submanifolds are you allowing (immersed, (weakly) embedded, etc.)? Also, how are you topologizing $M$ and $E$?

Comment: kinds of submanifolds: embedded (or maybe immersed if I need it?). I'm not sure what weakly embedded means but I'd like to not care about parameterizations.

Comment: As for topologizing: Is there a standard kind of topology on a manifold like M?

Comment: $M$ is not a manifold until you equip it with a topology (and perhaps not even then). There are all kinds of ways of topologizing the set of submanifolds, and without knowing why you're interested in this particular problem, there's no way of knowing which would be preferable.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195349/reference-request-topology-on-the-space-of-smooth-compact-submanifolds

How about this one?